# Prove or disprove there exists a Borel subset $F$ of $[0,1]$, such that $\mu(F)=a$ and $\mathcal{L}(F)=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Given $\mu$ a Borel probability measure on $[0,1]$, and $\mathcal{L}$ the Lebesgue measure restricted on $[0,1]$. $$a:=\sup \{ \mu(E) : \mathcal{L}(E) = \frac{1}{2}, ~E \text{ is a borel subset of [0,1]} \}$$
I want to show that there exists a Borel subset $F$ of $[0,1]$, such that $\mu(F)=a$ and $\mathcal{L}(F)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have phrased your question as an order. People here mostly don't like that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for your kind reminder, and I have revised my question.

Comment: OK. Now, there are still a few reasons why people are voting to close your question. You might want to have a read of https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question to see what the difficulty is.

Comment: Pick a sequence $(E_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of Borel sets in $[0,1]$ such that $\mathcal{L}(E_n)=\frac{1}{2}$ and such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu(E_n)=\alpha.$$ The set of indicator functions $1_{E_n}$ is bounded in $L^2([0,1])$ (wrt the Lebesgue measure). Using that the unit ball in a separable Hilbert space is weakly sequentially compact, we can pick a weakly converging subsequence $(1_{E_{n_k}})_{k\geq 1}$. Let $f\in L^2([0,1])$ be its weak limit. If you can show that $f$ is an indicator function, then you are done (its support should give you the desired $F$).

Comment: It might help to note that $$\mathcal{L}(E_{n_k})=\langle 1_{E_{n_k}}, 1_{[0,1]}\rangle_{L^2([0,1])},$$ which tells us $$\int_{[0,1]} f(x) dx=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Nice.

Comment: @copper.hat It would be even nicer if it would work :( Unfortunately the weak $L^2$ limit of indicator functions needs not be a indicator function. For example for $$E_n=\bigcup_{j=1}^n [(2j-1)\frac{1}{2n}, (2j)\frac{1}{2n}]\cup [1,2]$$ we have that $1_{E_n}$ converges weakly in $L^2([0,2])$ to $\frac{1}{2}1_{[0,1]}+1_{[1,2]}.$. So the argument does not quite work.

Comment: @copper.hat If you happen to have an idea how to approach this problem I'd love to hear about it. It bothers me that I don't see how to do it. It must be some probabilistic black magic :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I don't have any ideas at the moment. I tried some more mundane approaches to no avail (writing $\mu$ as a singular part and ac part).

Comment: @copper.hat Maybe one can show that $$\{1_E \ : \ E\subseteq [0,1] \text{ Borel measurable, }\mathcal{L}(E)=\frac{1}{2}\}$$ is compact in $L^1([0,1])$ via some inclusion exclusion (as $\vert 1_E-1_F\vert= 1_{E\Delta F}$) and then look at the converging subsequence.  The support of the limiting indicator function would be what we are looking for (passing to a yet another subsequence would give us pointwise convergence and thus by dominated convergence $\mu(E)=\int 1_E d \mu=\alpha$).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I think there is a more tedious, computational answer based on the Lebesgue decomposition, but I'm still grinding through the details. An approach along the lines you suggested would be much cleaner.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I added a tedious approach, I will check for mistakes in the morning. It is hackish even by my low standards.

Comment: @copper.hat I hope your computation works out. The compactness idea does not. The Fréchet–Kolmogorov theorem tells us that my set is not compact as for every tiny shift $\tau_h$ we can find $E$ such that $\Vert\tau_h 1_E-1_E\Vert_{L^p}=1$. Looking forward to read your answer in the morning.

Comment: The close brigade is at it again. This is a nontrivial question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a gruesome approach.

Using the Lebesgue decomposition theorem, write $\mu = \mu_s+\mu_a$ where $\mu_s \bot \mathcal{L}$ and $\mu_a \ll \mathcal{L}$. We can write $\mu_a (A) = \int_A g \ d \mathcal{L}$ for some ($\mathcal{L}$) integrable $g$.

In particular, the problem becomes $\mu_s[0,1]+\sup \{  \int_A g \ d \mathcal{L} \mid \mathcal{L}A = {1 \over 2} \}$.

Let $A_\alpha = g^{-1} [\alpha,\infty)$, $f(\alpha) = \mathcal{L} A_\alpha$ and note that $f$ is non increasing, the limit is zero and it is right continuous. The idea is to select a subset of measure ${1 \over 2}$ where $g$ has the 'largest value'.

Let $\alpha^* = \sup \{ \alpha \mid f(\alpha) \ge {1 \over 2}\}$.

If $f(\alpha^*) = {1 \over 2}$, then the answer is $\mu_s[0,1]+  \int_{A_{\alpha^*}} g \ d \mathcal{L}  $.

Otherwise, we have  $f(\alpha^*) > {1 \over 2}$ (that is, strictly greater than) and $f(\alpha) < {1 \over 2}$ for $\alpha > \alpha^*$.

Let $\Delta = g^{-1} \{ \alpha^*\}$ and note that $\mathcal{L} \Delta = f(\alpha^*) - \sup \{ f(\alpha) \mid \alpha > \alpha^* \}$.

Choose $B \subset \Delta$ such that $\mathcal{L} B = {1 \over 2 } - \sup \{ f(\alpha) \mid \alpha > \alpha^* \}$, and finally let $A = B \cup g^{-1} (\alpha,\infty)$, then the answer is
$\mu_s[0,1]+  \int_{A} g \ d \mathcal{L}  $.

Comment: That's pretty sweet!